# How to control time in Box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making a game using Libgdx and Box2d and I wan't to implement time control for the user similar to the sims, where the player can stop, fast forward and make time slower. I don't have a clear idea on how am I going to do that but I was thinking of `world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);`but I'm also not very familiar with it I just know that `.step()` method is used to update the Box2d world. So my question is how do you control time or if there is no time in box2d world how do you make everything move like if there was time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `world.step()`, the first parameter is the time to step by. Decreasing this will cause time to move slower, increasing this will cause time to move faster, setting it to `0` will cause time to stop. For example, changing it to this will cause time to move slower:

```
world.step(1 / 90f, 6, 2)
```

I believe - not tested!

Comment: thanks it works but can you please explain me what's the purpose of those three parameters, because I taught that the first parameter is used to set the fps of the world.

Comment: It tells you about it here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#stepping-the-simulation.